# Openshift - Can defined ConfigMap label values be used inside Deployment.yaml and how?

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift

I have defined a ConfigMap.yaml as below:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: studentmanager-config
  namespace: School
  labels:
    app: studentmanager
data:
  SCHOOL_CITY: ohio
```

and wonder if I can access the value of `app` which is `studentmanager` inside my studentmanager application Deployment.yaml. Maybe something like this?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
     labels:
       ......
    spec:
      .....
      containers:
        - name: ${labels.app}
          image: myimage.myrepo.com/${labels.app}:latest
          volumeMounts:
           ....
          env:
            ....
```

Tried by using ${labels.app} or $(labels.app) but none of them seem to work inside deployment yaml.

Comment: Try taking a look at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/downward_api.html#dapi-consuming-container-values, not sure if it would solve this _specific_ use case or not